# How to retrieve data from the database as objects?

Tags: php, oop

In Lynda.com PHP with MySQL Beyond the Basics, the author Kevin Skoglund introduced these methods as a way to retrieve data from the database as objects:

```
    public static function find_by_id($id)
    {
        global $database;
        $id = $database->escape($id);
        $result_array = static::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM " . static::$table_name . " WHERE id = {$id} LIMIT 1");
        return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
    }

    public static function find_by_sql($sql)
    {
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query($sql);
        $object_array = array();
        while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set))
        {
            $object_array[] = static::instantiate($row);
        }

        return $object_array;
    }

    protected static function instantiate($record)
    {
        $class_name = get_called_class();
        $object = new $class_name();
        foreach ($record as $attribute => $value)
        {
            if ($object->has_attribute($attribute))
            {
                $object->$attribute = $value;
            }
        }
        return $object;
    }
```

An example of using this inside a user class for instance would be:

```
$user = User::find_by_id(1);
echo $user->first_name;
```

My question is, if I have a table for posts for example, with a column named 'user' as a foreign key, and I try to retrieve a post using the aforementioned method, the user attribute will be just a number

```
$post = Post::find_by_id(1);
echo $post->user; // This will return the id of the user
```

However, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
echo $post->user->first_name;
```

How can I accomplish something like that? Would it involve using JOINs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want a ORM .. checkout Doctrine or Propel for example

Comment: I want to build something simple for myself for the purpose of learning.

Answer (score 0):

Read this documentation. This page explains mapping associations between objects.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html